# Processing the string separated by ":" with C#

Tags: c#, python, split

I need to parse the string separated with ":" to process the contents one by one.
I can implement the function with Python as follows:

```
st = "a:b:c"
h = st.split(":")
for item in h:
    print item
```

How can I do the same thing with C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var st = "a:b:c";
foreach(var item in st.Split(':'))
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string st = "a:b:c";
foreach(string item in st.Split(':'))
    Console.Write(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

C# has a [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) function as well, you shouldn't need to change anything in your approach except the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much identical to Python:

```
var myString = "a:b:c";
var splitString = myString.Split(':');
foreach(var item in splitString)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```